# How to not use blank input values in a query when submitted in a form

Tags: django, forms, python-3.x, django-views

How do I not let my form use blank inputted data in a query?

I want the user to be able to fill in either the Incident ID field or the Equipment ID field. I want the user to have the option to leave either field blank. I want the query to search only what is inputted.

For example: If a user enters in Incident ID '6' and leaves Equipment ID '', I want the query to work using Incident ID.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.db.models import Q

from .models import Incident
from .models import Equipment


class IncidentForm(forms.Form):
    incident_id = forms.CharField(required=False)
    equipment_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(Equipment.objects.all(), required=False, widget=forms.TextInput)

    #def clean(self):
    # I'd use the clean method to force the user to provide either an incident or equipment value

    def search(self):
        return Incident.objects.filter(
            Q(id=self.cleaned_data['incident_id']) &
            Q(equipment_id=self.cleaned_data['equipment_id'])
        )
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .forms import IncidentForm
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView 

from .models import Incident


def index(request):

    template = "index.html"

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = IncidentForm(request.GET)
        #incident_list = None
        if 'equipment_id' in request.GET or 'incident_id' in request.GET:
        incident_list = None
            if form.is_valid():
                incident_list = form.search()
                context = { "form": form,
                            "incident_list": incident_list}
                return render(request, template, context)
        else:
            # form is empty show all OPEN incidents
            form = IncidentForm()
            incident_list = Incident.objects.filter(open = 'True').order_by('-incident_date_time_reported')
            context = { "form": form,
                        "incident_list": incident_list}
            return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in this?

Comment: when i leave one input field blank

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def search(self):

cust_id = self.cleaned_data['incident_id'] or ''
equip_id =  self.cleaned_data['equipment_id'] or ''
return Incident.objects.filter(
        Q(id=cust_id) &
        Q(equipment_id=equip_id)
    )
```

Comment: This is the error I'm getting with it. `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Answer (score 0):

this is an alternate form of the answer provided by Ajay Gupta

```
self.cleaned_data.get('incident_id', '')
```

Comment: I'm still getting the `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` error. Does it have something to do with the data type?

Comment: at some point you seem to be calling `int(cust_id)` (or `int(incident_id)` ); if `cust_id == ''` then this will be the exception that is raised. you could try `self.cleaned_data.get('incident_id', -1)` (assuming these ids are never negative) as an (unelegant!) workaround.

Comment: I understand. It expects an int and I'm giving it ' '. Can you direct me to where I'm calling int(cust_id)? Do most people use this workaround?

Comment: How can I set up a query in such a way to not use empty strings ''? Do I have to check all the user input variables for empty strings? and then use the non-empty strings in query specific searches?

Comment: your `Q` probably declares `id` to be an `int`. i assume the conversion is done there somewhere. and no: i would  not use the workaround. check if an id exists; if  it does not handle the case accordingly (i.e. return something different from what you return now).